# SQL Server : splitting a column to multiple columns with joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables A, B, C

Table A

```
sID sName
1   Apple
2   Banana
3   Cherry
```

Table B

```
PointID PointName sID
1       seed      1
2       seed      2
3       stem      1
4       stem      2
5       stem      3
6       root      2
7       leave     1
```

Table C

```
PointID Time                  pointValue
1       2013-03-15 12:00:00   23.0
2       2013-03-15 12:00:00   24.0
5       2013-03-15 12:00:00   25.0
1       2013-03-15 13:00:00   26.0
2       2013-03-15 13:00:00   27.0
6       2013-03-15 13:00:00   28.0
2       2013-03-16 13:00:00   29.0
6       2013-03-16 13:00:00   30.0
7       2013-03-15 13:00:00   31.0
```

I will need the output to be like this (simply show all result filtered by time):

```
Time                  sName    seed    stem   root
2013-03-15 12:00:00   Apple    23.0    NULL   NULL 
2013-03-15 12:00:00   Banana   24.0    NULL   NULL
2013-03-15 12:00:00   Cherry   NULL    25.0   NULL
2013-03-15 13:00:00   Apple    26.0    NULL   NULL   
2013-03-15 13:00:00   Banana   27.0    NULL   28.0
```

I have came up with a solution using multiple joins, however my results do show the time and sName with seed, stem, root as NULL due to the pointName "leave" not being required.

```
SELECT HEADER.TIME
    ,HEADER.sName
    ,SD.seed
    ,STM.stem
    ,RT.root
FROM (
    SELECT C.TIME
        ,A.sName
    FROM B
    INNER JOIN C ON B.PointID = C.PointID
    INNER JOIN A ON B.sID = A.sID
    ) HEADER
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT C.TIME
        ,A.sName
    FROM B
    INNER JOIN C ON B.PointID = C.PointID
    INNER JOIN A ON B.sID = A.sID
    WHERE B.PointName = "seed"
    ) SD ON HEADER.TIME = SD.TIME
    AND HEADER.sName = SD.sName
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT C.TIME
        ,A.sName
    FROM B
    INNER JOIN C ON B.PointID = C.PointID
    INNER JOIN A ON B.sID = A.sID
    WHERE B.PointName = "stem"
    ) STM ON HEADER.TIME = STM.TIME
    AND HEADER.sName = STM.sName
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT C.TIME
        ,A.sName
    FROM B
    INNER JOIN C ON B.PointID = C.PointID
    INNER JOIN A ON B.sID = A.sID
    WHERE B.PointName = "root"
    ) RT ON HEADER.TIME = RT.TIME
    AND HEADER.sName = RT.sName
WHERE (HEADER.TIME > '2013-03-15 11:00:00')
    AND (HEADER.TIME < '2013-03-16 20:00:00')
```

I have attempted to add a OR clause in the most outer where clause to check if one of the 3 columns are not null. But got no return results instead

```
WHERE (HEADER.Time > '2013-03-15 11:00:00') AND (HEADER.Time < '2013-03-16 20:00:00') 
AND (SD.seed <> NULL OR STM.stem <> NULL OR RT.root <> NULL)
```

It will be great to have the NULL selection solved, or comment if there is a better solution? As I am unsure if my current method will be good on a implementation with even more multiple columns to be

Comment: I'd change some of the **FULL JOIN**s to **INNER JOIN**s first, but only if I know that I will only have data between those two tables, so the `JOIN` condition will be always true and return data when it's matching. This will improve the performace of your query, for starters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you'll need a [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this, given the need to project row data across into columns:

```
SELECT Date, sName, [seed], [stem], [root], [leave]
FROM
(
   SELECT DATE, [PointName], [sName], PointValue
   FROM C 
     LEFT JOIN B ON C.PointID = B.POINTID
     LEFT JOIN A ON B.[sID] = A.[sID]
) p
PIVOT
(
  SUM(PointValue)
  FOR [PointName] IN ( [seed], [stem], [root], [leave])
) y;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52f91/2)

Comment: This looks good! but I will need to filter by the Dates as well and I am unsure how to go about placing that where clause in a pivot.

Comment: Add the filter into the inner SELECT - i.e. `SELECT DATE ... FROM C ... **WHERE DATE >= X and DATE < y**) p ...`. I also saw you didn't want leaves - if so, just filter it out in the inner select, and also drop the column from the top and bottom pivot columns

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem! However, the current database had the PointValue stored as a nvarchar(MAX) thus I wasn't able to SUM it. my attempt to SUM(CAST(PointValue as double)) only returned me error of incorrect syntax.